# Automatically updating function after changing a single cell

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to get familiar with the `rhandsontable` package. So I tried something I thought should be pretty easy but I can't find a solution. Here is the idea:

I am creating a dataframe with random numbers and in a text box. The mean of column 1 of the dataframe should be displayed. Furthermore, that number should be updated as soon as I change the value of a cell in the dataframe.

My code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("num"),
  rHandsontableOutput(outputId="frame")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  datavalue <- reactiveValues(data=df)

  observeEvent(input$frame$changes$changes,{
    mean_col1 <- mean(datavalue$data[[1]][1:10])   
  })        

  output$num <- renderText({
    mean(datavalue$data[[1]][1:10])
  })

  output$frame <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(datavalue$data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `hot_to_r` to convert the handsontable to an R object when there is a change. You can update your `reactiveValue` `datavalue$data` when that happens, and your `output$num` will account for this change as well with the new mean.

Try using this in your `observeEvent`:

```
datavalue$data <- hot_to_r(input$frame)
```

As an alternative, you can do a general `observe` as follows:

```
observe({
  req(input$frame)
  datavalue$data <- hot_to_r(input$frame)
})
```

Comment: That helped. I tried the alternative solution and it worked.

Comment: Great! If helpful feel free to [upvote or accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).